# WordPress: Is it possible to add a widget to footer/sidebar on widget activation?

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer, sidebar

I have managed to follow [fuxia's solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26557/programmatically-add-widgets-to-sidebars) on adding a default widget to the footer sidebar but the widget doesnt seem to be "activated" (I have to remove and manually add it back to the footer sidebar for the widget to work, making the pre-set widget code pointless). I found that the widget added by the aforementioned solution and the same widget pulled from the list of available widgets are different. The picture below shows different href values for the widget items in the footer list of widgets. (Grey boxes are just the widget name)
[image: WidgetDiffs]

I'm not sure if this is the reason behind the issue but is there a way to add the widget to the footer sidebar AND have it work/"activated"?

EDIT: current implementation

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget( 'MyWidget' );

    $sidebars = array ('a' => 'sidebar-1' );
    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ) {
      register_sidebar(array (
      'name' => 'Footer',
      'id' => $sidebar,
      'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
      'after_title' => '</h2>'
      ));
    }

    $active_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
    if ( ! empty ( $active_widgets[ $sidebars['a'] ] )){ 
    return; }
    $counter = 1;
    $active_widgets[$sidebars['a']][0] = 'my_widget-'.$counter;
    update_option('sidebars_widgets',$active_widgets);
    dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with the following code?

functions. php

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_sidebars' );

/*Custom widgets*/
function aavishkaar_custom_sidebars(){

register_sidebar(
      array (
           'name'          =>  __( 'Footerwidget', 'Aavishkaar' ),
           'id'            =>  'footer-widget1',
           'description'   =>  __( 'Footer widget', 'Aavishkaar' ),
           'before_widget' =>  '<div class="col-md-2 col-3 footer-pd_0 widget_ul">',
           'after_widget'  =>  "</div>",


    )
);

}

Then add menu to this and call it by  <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-widget1');?>
```

Comment: Hi, could you review the edited part of my question? It seem to be inline with your code yet i'm still facing the href difference issue